# Перегрузка функции в си с разным количеством аргументов

Tags: c, функции, аргументы, перегрузка-функций

Нужно реализовать на си инициализацию списка с/без данных для первого блока.
Нужна одна функция для инициализации, но или с одним int параметром, или без параметров вовсе. Хотелось бы получить что-то вроде этого, но код не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *initializewithdata(int data) {
    node *head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->data = data;
    return head;
}

node *initializewithoutdata() {
    node *head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

#define initializelist(X) _Generic((X), int: initializewithdata, default: initializewithoutdata)(X)
#define initializelist() initializewithoutdata()

int main() {
    node *head = initializelist();
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Да, я знаю, что для перегрузки стоило бы использовать C++. Мне нужен именно си

Comment: В данном конкретном  случае — плохое решение, так как при инициализации без данных получите мусор... :)

Comment: Можно инициализировать с data=0, никто не запрещает

Comment: На первый взгляд перегрузка выглядит привлекательно. Но с опытом отладки (особенно чужих программ) приходит понимание, что на самом деле это плохая фича, лучше программировать без нее.

Answer (score 1):

В си так делать нельзя - в языке си перегрузки в данном виде нет, можно вывернуться через дженерик макросы или дефайны, может быть, но в данном виде в Си перегрузки нет

Comment: Но ведь ТС это же и написал? "Да, я знаю, что для перегрузки стоило бы использовать C++. Мне нужен именно си"